# Rails Group By Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this method to return a report. This will return something like this:

```
+------------+----+---------+--------+----------+
|   dates    | id |  name   | amount | purchase |
+------------+----+---------+--------+----------+
| 2015-02-10 |  1 | Private |    100 |       30 |
| 2015-02-10 |  2 | Public  |    250 |       45 |
| 2015-02-20 |  1 | Private |    200 |       20 |
| 2015-02-20 |  2 | Public  |    150 |       25 |
+------------+----+---------+--------+----------+
```

After I got this table, I want to apply mark-up percentage in the `amount`. The percentage is different between date. Below is the table after mark up. For date 2015-02-10, the percentage is 10% and 20% for 2015-02-20.

```
+------------+----+---------+--------+----------+
|   dates    | id |  name   | amount | purchase |
+------------+----+---------+--------+----------+
| 2015-02-10 |  1 | Private |    110 |       30 |
| 2015-02-10 |  2 | Public  |    275 |       45 |
| 2015-02-20 |  1 | Private |    240 |       20 |
| 2015-02-20 |  2 | Public  |    180 |       25 |
+------------+----+---------+--------+----------+
```

This is my code so far.

```
def self.report(school_id)
  items = Transaction.joins("JOIN categories ON categories.id = transactions.category_id")

  items = items.select("date(from_unixtime(transactions.unix_timestamp)) as dates")
  items = items.select("categories.id")
  items = items.select("categories.name")
  items = items.select("sum(transactions.amount) as amount")
  items = items.select("avg(transactions.purchase) as purchase")

  items = items.where("categories.school_id = ?", school_id)

  items = items.group("categories.id")
  items = items.group("date(from_unixtime(transactions.unix_timestamp))")

  items.map do |x|
    p = Percentage.where(date: 'x[:dates]').limit(1).first.percentage
    x[:amount] = x[amount] * (100 + p) / 100
  end

  items
end
```

After mark up process, I want to group them by `id` and the expected result is like this. The amount will be summed and purchase will be averaged.

```
+----+---------+--------+----------+
| id |  name   | amount | purchase |
+----+---------+--------+----------+
|  1 | Private |    350 |       25 |
|  2 | Public  |    455 |       35 |
+----+---------+--------+----------+
```

I got confused on how to group it by `id` because I tried to use `items.group(...)` and the items is not grouped.

Comment: do you have different percentages for the same date ? or why are you doing the .limit(1).first.percentage ?

Comment: Yes, actually it's more complex than that. My question is the simple version.

Answer (score 0):

Try change this line:

```
items = items.select("sum(transactions.amount) as amount")
```

to

```
items = items.select("sum(CASE WHEN DATE(dates)=DATE('2015-02-10') THEN transactions.amount*1.1 WHEN DATE(dates)=DATE('2015-02-20') THEN transactions.amount*1.2 ELSE transactions.amount END) as amount")
```

Comment: The percentage is dynamic. I got it from `Percentage` model. Please look at the last 6th line. Thank you.